# XCode 4 Will Not Build With My Static Framework?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, frameworks, xcode4

Download the source from here for reference: https://github.com/MochiCart/MochiCartSDK-IOS

Hey guys, I'm trying to figure out why the framework I've developed isn't building in XCode 4, but builds fine in XCode 5? When I run the sample cart app I have in my framework folder on the github repository in XCode 4, I get about 80 different compiler errors relating to linker errors against AVFoundation and MessageUI.

What I'm totally confused about is why the sample app runs fine on XCode 5, yet XCode 4 it doesn't even come close.

The static framework was compiled with XCode 5, would that make a difference?

Comment: why do you want to support Xcode 4?

Comment: The framework is available to anyone who wants to integrate a shopping cart into their app - some people have not yet upgraded to XCode 5, which is a problem if they want to use this. I'm trying to figure out why individuals still running xcode 4 have compiler issues with default ios libraries?

Comment: There are numerous reasons why an attempt to stick with Xcode 4 is a really bad idea including: Apple requires new submissions be compiled with Xcode 5; and, Xcode 4 can't connect to and/or debug devices running iOS 7 (and maybe even iOS 6).